# docker-compose v3 prepend folder name to network name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

When I run `docker-compose up -d`, docker always creates container name and network name prepended with the folder name that contains `docker-compose.yml`file.

I can specify the container name as follows:

```
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: .docker/docker-nginx.dockerfile
```

But how can I specify the network name so that it doesn't prepend folder name to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Docker Prepends the current folder name with all the components name created using docker compose file.

Eg : If the current folder name containing the docker-compose.yml file is test, all the volumes,network and container names will get test appended to it. In order to solve the problem people earlier proposed the idea of using **-p** flag with docker-compose command but the solution is not the most feasible one as a project name is required just after the -p attribute. The project name then gets appended to all the components created using docker compose file.

The **Solution** to the above problem is using the **name** property as in below.

```
volumes: 
  data:
    driver: local
    name: mongodata

networks: 
  internal-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: frontend-network
```

This volume can be referred in the service section as

```
services:
  mongo-database:
      volumes: 
        - data:/data/db
      networks: 
        - internal-network
```

The above **name** attribute will prevent docker-compose to prepend folder name.

Note : For the container name one could use the property **container_name**

```
services:
  mongo-database:
    container_name: mongo
```

Comment: Extremely useful reference, never knew about the network `name` attribute.  I have used `container_name` before but had to come here to refresh my mind on using it.   Would it be possible to update the example with `-p flag` , I do not see any reference on `docker-compose up --help`, and as far as I know `-p` for `docker run` is for ports?

Comment: Yes are correct -p is for ports and that could be done in docker compose using
ports:
     - '30050:8161'
Be careful with the alignment. You can use vs code with docker-compose extension to get this done easily

Comment: The point was that your answer alluded to `-p` and its usage, it sort of suggested that you could use it to create `--project-name`, which are two different concepts.  Just wanted to try and clear that up for future readers (and me).

Answer (score 10):

You have to place a ".env" file in the root of your docker-compose project directory.

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=MyFancyProject
```

See Docker docs for further information: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/

If you don't use docker-compose, you can use the "`-p`" parameter to set this on `docker run`.

Comment: then docker will prepend the project name instead of folder name, right?

Comment: For the record, the `-p` argument is also supported by `docker-compose` command line.

Comment: Why can't I just specify the name in the compose file? This makes no sense. The purpose of the compose file is to describe the project right? The name of the project isn't a variable, and other things may depend on it being a static value so that it can be referenced.

Comment: The project name now can also be set by the top level `name` property. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44924392/368613).