# Set $PROJECT_NAME in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using the same `docker-compose.yml` file for multiple projects. I am really lazy, so I don't want to start them with `docker-compose -p $PROJECT_NAME up`.

**As of Docker version 17.06.0, is it possible to set the variable directly in the `docker-compose.yml` file?**

Comment: what is the name of the variable? I cannot find in the docs

Comment: Please clarify or add a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

**UPDATE**: You can now use the top-level [name](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#name-top-level-element) property in your docker-compose YAML file. This is available from Docker Compose v2.3.3

This is the result of the [#745](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745) proposal. An issue which persevered for about 8 years.

**Previously:**
Right now, we can use [the `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) to set the custom project name like this:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=SOMEPROJECTNAME
```

It's not flexible, but it's better than nothing. Currently, there is [an open issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745) regarding this as a proposal.

Comment: Compose supports declaring default environment variables in an environment file named `.env` placed in the folder where the `docker-compose` command is executed (current working directory).

Comment: It silly that for all this time they still can't add this little feature directly in compose file. Whats their reasoning for not doing it? What if I want to run docker-compose in same dir for multiple projects? Then `.env` file is useless

Comment: With newer versions of Docker Compose, this can now be done in the `docker-compose.yml` file with the `name:` property (see @Michal's answer).

Comment: Example docker-compose.yml (replace \n with a new line in your editor):

version: "3"\n
name: projectName\n
services:\n

Answer (score 17):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but I ran into the same problem. There's a suggestion to add the feature https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745, but they don't want to.

However, I have a Makefile in the root of the directory and then you can add something like in the Makefile:

```
.PHONY: container-name
container-name:
    docker-compose -p $PROJECT_NAME up -d container-name
```

and then run `make container-name`

I know it isn't what you asked for, but could maybe make your life a bit easier.

Comment: great solution, better than creating an .env file, thanks!

Comment: Hey, it looks like they might be implementing this soon. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745#issuecomment-1025146862

Answer (score 8):

**220806 UPDATE**: you can now use the top-level [name](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#name-top-level-element) property in your docker-compose YAML file.

This is the result of the [#745](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745) proposal.

Comment: According to the comments in the GitHub ticket, from at least Docker Compose v2.3.3.

Answer (score 4):

Update as on Docker Compose version 2.3.3, name can be given in the compose file, but please note the following as per documentation [compose-spec at github.com](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#name-top-level-element)., [Compose official documentation](https://name:%20stitch%20services:%20%20%20foo:%20%20%20%20%20image:%20busybox%20%20%20%20%20environment:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME%20%20%20%20%20command:%20echo)

> Whenever project name is defined by top-level name or by some custom mechanism, it MUST be exposed for interpolation and environment variable resolution as COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME.

```
name: stitch
services:
  foo:
    image: busybox
    environment:
      - COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME
    command: echo "I'm running ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}"
```

Previously proposed solution :
You can add them as your environment variables which are available through the session in which you are bringing up your containers using the docker compose.

Ie, if you wanted to use $PROJECT_NAME somewhere inside your docker-compose.yaml then if this variable has a value in your session, then it would be picked up.

Inside the yaml you can assign it to anything as you want it. You want as a commandline arg to some script, even that is also possible. ie,

```
working_dir: /opt
command: /bin/bash -c './script.sh ${PROJECT_NAME}'
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
```

I'm using
docker version : Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
docker-compose version : docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e

Answer (score 0):

in your project ROOT dir make **.env** file
put line

```
PROJECT_NAME=yourprojectname
```

no need to add any key in **docker-compose.yml**