# How to create multiple containers of same image by running same docker-compose file on different host ports?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Suppose currently I am running a docker container `Container A` created using Image `Image X` running on Host Port `3031` and Docker Port `3030`

`DOCKER_COMPOSE.yaml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: ${IMAGENAME}
    container_name: ${PROJECTNAME}_ContainerA
    restart: ${RESTART}
    build:
      context: ${BUILD}
      args:
        PORT: 3030       --> this goes to dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3031:3030"
    networks:
      salesdb_network:
        ipv4_address: ${IP}
    environment:
      - APP_PORT=3030

networks:
  some_network:
    external: true
```

**I AM GETTING PORTS FROM env file**. Above is just for demonstration

I ran `docker-compose --env-file **some_file** -f docker-compose.yaml up`

[image]

Till now, Works fine. All good No Issues.

Now, 
I want to create another container `Container B` by using Image `Image X` running on Host Port `3033` and Docker Port `3032`. I have same structure as above for `docker_compose.yaml` file with changed ports

I ran `docker-compose --env-file **some_file_2** -f docker-compose.yaml up`

But, I get following error.

```
creating ${PROJECTNAME}_ContainerA... error

ERROR: for ${PROJECTNAME}_ContainerA  Cannot start service app: Address already in use

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: Address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Before I added PROJECTNAME (for which i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924082/set-project-name-in-docker-compose-file)), While running `Container B`, It used to Override `Container A` 
AND Ports would change to `3031/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3033->3032/tcp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother changing the port in your Dockerfile, let the app listen on the same port inside of every container. Each container has a separate network namespace, so they won't conflict. What you do need to change is the published port on the host. Change this:

```
ports:
  - "3031:3030"
```

to use a variable like:

```
ports:
  - "${PORT}:3030"
```

And then define your `$PORT` environment variable in a `.env` or in your shell before running the `docker-compose up`.

---

I'd also recommend removing the following:

```
    ipv4_address: ${IP}
```

Instead let docker provision an IP on that network and use DNS to find your container between containers. Since everything is the same service name, you can use your container name `${PROJECTNAME}_ContainerA`, or give your containers a unique network alias:

```
networks:
  salesdb_network:
    aliases:
    - ${PROJECTNAME}-app
```

Comment: Hi @BMitch, Thanks for the reply. I tried it just to be sure. But I am still getting same error.

Comment: @Anurag then it's probably your static IP address that's conflicting. I'd avoid using that, see the edit above.

Comment: Hi BMitch. That is correct. It was the IP that was creating the issue. Thanks a lot.