# docker-compose change name of main container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a simple frontend and backend app. And I have a docker-compose file but it's inside frontend folder. So when I run it both frontend and backend containers are under frontend container (it takes name of the folder) how can I rename this main container? I am using version 3.9

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  be_service:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ../backend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8089:8080"
  fe_service:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    depends_on:
      - be_service
```

Comment: Are both containers running the same code (I'd find that a little surprising)?  Which thing "takes the name of the folder"?  (Also see the [COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variable, which is involved in naming Docker-level objects.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks that was the thing :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set $PROJECT\_NAME in docker-compose file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924082/set-project-name-in-docker-compose-file)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Related to [Docker Compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) you can set your project name with:

```
docker-compose -p app up --build
```

with `-p app` to set your compose container name to `app`.

Answer (score 59):

When refering to your *main container*, you are probably refering to the project name, which you could usually set via the `-p` flag. (See other answers)

For `docker-compose`, you can set the top level variable `name` to your desired project name.

docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
name: my-project-name
services:
  myService:
    ...
```

If you are using Docker Desktop, make sure `Use Docker Compose V2` is enabled there.

Comment: that's give error:  ERROR: The Compose file '.\..\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
'name' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'.   EDIT: Enabling "Use Docker Compose V2" in Docker Desktop fixed the problem

Comment: I downvoted because I got the same error. Then the fix @HuguesGauthier came up with fixed it for me too. However, StackOverflow has not locked my downvote and I cannot change my vote until you update your answer with the fix. Just a friendly heads up.

Comment: yeah this is not working for me either in 2023. The solution suggested by @HuguesGauthier(aka Nguyen Ho) is not for docker-compose.yml file. Is there a way to set this directly in the file itself?

Comment: Be carefull with the name of the project  : From the doc : Project names must contain only lowercase letters, decimal digits, dashes, and underscores, and must begin with a lowercase letter or decimal digit.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your docker compose file is right and to change the co you can use the containe_name instruction but I think you should run this command when you want to run your application :

```bash
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: What did you change? Your docker-compose.yml looks exactly like in the question.

Comment: I mentioned that you should only use the command but the docker-compose file still the same please read what I mentioned before the command , thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Use -p to specify a project name**

Each configuration has a project name. If you supply a -p flag, you can specify a project name. If you don’t specify the flag, Compose uses the current directory name.

Calling `docker-compose --profile frontend up` will start the services with the profile frontend and services without specified profiles. You can also enable multiple profiles, e.g. with `docker-compose --profile frontend --profile debug up` the profiles frontend and debug will be enabled

Also refer  https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/