# Restart entire docker compose stack from one of the containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any proper way of restarting an entire `docker compose` stack from within one of its containers?

One workaround involves mounting the docker socket:

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

and then use the Docker Engine SDKs (https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/).

However, this solution only allows restarting the containers itselves. There seems to be no way to send compose commands, like `docker compose restart`, `docker compose up`, etc.

The only solution I've found to send `docker compose` commands is to open a terminal on the host from the container using ssh, like this: [access host's ssh tunnel from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143689/access-hosts-ssh-tunnel-from-docker-container)

This is partly related to [How to run shell script on host from docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163955/how-to-run-shell-script-on-host-from-docker-container) , but I'm actually looking for a more specific solution to only send `docker compose` commands.

Comment: If you have docker and docker compose installed in the container, you should be able to do what you want by mapping the socket.

Comment: `There seems to be no way to send compose commands, like docker compose restart, docker compose up` ? Why? What happens if you do? There is a way, just execute them, the same way.

Comment: ...and if you do make the Docker socket available as @HansKilian suggests, it gives the container unrestricted root-level access over the entire host system.  (Without Docker, the application rebooting the host would accomplish this; do you want that capability?)  Unless you're trying to write some sort of remote-administration tool (and then I'd separate it from the application) I'd suggest just skipping over this capability.

Comment: `If you have docker and docker compose installed in the container, you should be able to do what you want by mapping the socket.` As I've mentioned, restarting containers is definitely possible by mapping the socket. Using docker compose commands however requires the `docker-compose.yml` file inside the container itself, and even if I map the file from the host to the container, the commands get executed inside the container, which is not what I'm trying to achieve (I need them executed on the host). In fact, docker compose sees no services running inside the container (obviously).

Comment: Why doesn't compose see the services? You say "obviously" but it's not obvious unless you are connecting to a different engine? My suspicion is you have set a different compose project name (or changed the directory name inside the container which has the same effect).

Comment: The best advice you're getting here is from David. If you aren't building a management service that can be separate from the application, then you're creating a significant security risk. This would be better done by the application itself. Maybe a trigger file shared by a volume that the containers see has a newer date than their start time that triggers an exit.

Comment: `My suspicion is you have set a different compose project name (or changed the directory name inside the container which has the same effect). ` That's the answer. Updating OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @BMitch in the comments, compose project name was the reason why I wasn't able to run docker compose commands inside the running container.

By default the compose project name is set to the directory name, so if the `docker-compose.yml` is run from a host directory named `folder1`, then the commands inside the container should be run as:

```
docker-compose -p folder1 ...
```

So now, for example, restarting the stack works:

```
docker-compose -p folder1 restart
```

Just as a reference, a fixed project name for your compose can be set using `name: ...` as a top-level attribute of the `.yml` file, but requires docker compose v2.3.3 : [Set $PROJECT_NAME in docker-compose file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924082/set-project-name-in-docker-compose-file)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this simple docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 3000:80
```

Then I started a `docker` container using

```
docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(pwd):/work docker
```

Then, inside the container, I did

```
cd /work
docker-compose up -d
```

and it started the container up on the host.

Please note that you have an error in your socket mapping. It needs to be

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

(you have a period instead of a slash at one point)

Comment: Ok so by running the container using docker, NOT docker-compose, and then running `docker-compose up` inside, it works. However, if I try to restart the stack from inside the container, `docker-compose restart` I get:
```ERROR: No containers to restart
``` cause docker-compose does not see the running services on the host.

Comment: It's kind of hard to know why you're getting errors, when all you've shown of your setup is a single line of a docker-compose file.

Comment: Try `docker-compose restart` inside the container :) Just to be clear, `docker restart` works fine.

Comment: project-name was the reason, thanks for your example anyway :)